# Receive this error from installed package 'System.QueryException: sObject type 'CollaborationGroup' is not supported.'

Tags: chatter, scheduled-apex

I am getting the error -

`'System.QueryException: sObject type 'CollaborationGroup' is not supported.'`

When running the following code as part of a managed package by scheduled apex:

> List groups = [select id, name, description from
>   collaborationGroup];

What's strange is that the code works if I run it in the developer console but not when it runs from scheduled apex (setup as part of a post install script).

I've got 'with sharing on' so could it be down to the installer user profile? It works in some installed instances but not others but can't see a reason e.g. SFDC edition, profile, chatter settings, etc...

I do know that Chatter has to be enabled but that is the case anyway in the partnerforce dev orgs.

What am I missing here?

Comment: So you are executing this code as part of a Post Install Script? Is the code that runs the query in the same file as the Install Script, or is it stored in another file (e.g. in a utility class, or in your scheduled apex class)?

Comment: Couple of thoughts. Check if chatter is enabled using something like if (Schema.SObjectType.User.isFeedEnabled()). Secondly check if the Api version of the class running the query is recent so that CollborationGroups are supported?

Comment: @techtrekker - api version is 25 so should be ok. I'm investigating the setup in the orgs where the error occurs to see if anything looks wrong. For reference, if chatter isn't enabled then the package won't install at all. I (presume) then that chatter couldn't be turned off as this code would be present...

Comment: @zachelrath - The code is in a separate utility file called from the postinstall script.

Comment: I got a feeling this has to do with the user profile. Are you sure the user that's executing this code has enough privileges to read CollaborationGroups?

Answer (score 4):

Your code must be run in a `without sharing` context in order for it to have access to the `CollaborationGroup` SObject. I'm guessing that your Utility class which contains the query is *not* explicitly declared as `without sharing`, so you can do one of two things:

1. Move all of your code into your actual PostInstall Script Apex class (the one that implements `InstallHandler`).
2. If possible, change the signature of your Utility class to be `without sharing`.
3. Extract out the particular logic that executes this query into a separate Utility class that is declared as `without sharing`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your querying for `Group`, as in a [user group](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_group.htm) instead of a `Collaboration Group` *which is the API name for a [Chatter group](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm)*

```
List<CollaborationGroup> chatterGroups = [SELECT Id FROM CollaborationGroup];
```

vs.

```
List<Group> groups = [SELECT Id FROM Group];
```

Try explicitly querying for `CollaborationGroup` to get the type correct

Comment: Thx for the comment, already setting the collection 'groups' to be of type CollaborationGroup just didn't add it correctly to the post ;(.